# How to use rancher2 behind traefik2

Tags: traefik, rancher

i'm trying to set up rancher2 behind a proxy traefik2  with docker-compose, but after several tries and days, i've alway a refused connection on https://rancher2.docker.localhost.

I try to setup an nginx container behind traefik2 and there is no problem expect with https.

Someone can show me how to solve this problem (rancher2 behind traefik2)

Thx

Edit :
0

@ZF007 thx for you intention

i have nothing in log rancher2 or traefik2, i've try whith different middleware traefik, redirect https

The last try seems like this : rancher2:
    image: rancher/rancher:latest
    container_name: rancher2
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.rancher2.rule=Host(rancher2.docker.localhost)
      - traefik.http.routers.web-secure.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.rancher2.middlewares=rancher2-mw
      - traefik.http.middlewares.rancher2-mw.redirectscheme.scheme=https
    environment:
      - NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,192.168.10.0/24,172.20.0.0/24,example.com"
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443 and the error is => ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: explain briefly a few methods you tried to install. Any short summary of an error reporting log to share? (From Review).

Comment: could you provide the docker compose?

Comment: and traefik conf too